# System.Text.JSON 6.0.2 version and above throw error with JsonSerializer.Deserialize

Tags: .net, system.text.json, fileloadexception

I have created a basic template Class library (see image below) and added just one reference system.text.json (version 6.0.2) through manage nuggets

[image]

[image]

Created a Console application with the above Class library as reference. (basic template just added reference to the class library)

[image]

Is throws error starting version 6.0.2 and tested 6.0.3 and 6.0.4 as well same issue whenever this code is existing JsonSerializer.Deserialize

Am I missing prerequisite reference to make this work ? Have tried the binding redirect with no success either. Please Advise

Below are the version of the framework used

[image]

Comment: What's the version of your .net

Comment: I have update the question to add the framework details of the Console (.NET 5.0) and Class library (.NET Framework 4.8)

Comment: You might need to use  `.NET Standard` instead of in `.NET Framework 4.8` Class library, because `.NET Framework 4.8` might not use in .net core

Comment: otherwise, you might use `.NET 5.0` for your  Class library

Comment: According to their link https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json .Net Framework is supported not sure why is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade "system.text.json" version in console application.
Root cause : In class library some of the reference have dependency with "system.text.json" versions that you have in class library project but not console application.